# Celery - RabbitMQ as a Service - Broker Secure Connection (TSL/SSL) - Message Signing

Tags: security, ssl, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I am trying to configure [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/) on my Django web server securely and I can figure out two alternatives on achieving this. Either securing the broker or signing the messages.

- Celery, needs a message broker in which case is [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html).

  I am using a "RabbitMQ as a service" implementation, which means that the RabbitMQ server is reached through the internet using the [amqp](https://www.amqp.org/) protocol.

  The service provider distributes an [amqp uri](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html), and also supports amqps:

  > The "amqps" URI scheme is used to instruct a client to make an secured connection to the server.

  - [Apparently](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/security.html#broker), this is what I need, otherwise all my messages will be circulating around the net, naked on the wire.

  In order to use amqps, celery needs the following [configuration](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=ssl#std:setting-BROKER_USE_SSL):

  ```
  import ssl

  BROKER_USE_SSL = {
    'keyfile': '/var/ssl/private/worker-key.pem',
    'certfile': '/var/ssl/amqp-server-cert.pem',
    'ca_certs': '/var/ssl/myca.pem',
    'cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
  }
  ```

  **Question:**
  Where can I find those `.pem` files?

  According to [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html), I have to create them myself and configure the RabbitMQ server to use them.

  However, I am not running the server. As stated above I have a "RabbitMQ as a service" provider who supports amqps. Should I ask him to provide me with those `.pem` files?
- Celery, can also [sign messages](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/security.html#message-signing).

  (Trying this approach, I get a `No encoder installed for auth` error which [I reported](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3445).)

  **Question:** Does this mean that I can use my certificates to secure the connection as an alternative configuration to `BROKER_USE_SSL`?

  There is also a note regarding message signing:

  > auth serializer won’t encrypt the contents of a message, so if needed
  >   this will have to be enabled separately.

  **Subquestion:** Does encrypting the contents of a message protect me from the "current" RabbitMQ server administrator while "message signing" only protects me while on the wire towards that server?

Apparently I am somehow confused but I would not like to create any kind of insecure traffic over the internet for any reason. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When configuring for [CloudAMQP](http://www.cloudamqp.com), you need to set BROKER_USE_SSL to True and the BROKER_URL as shown below:

`BROKER_USE_SSL = True`

`BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:pass@hostname:5671/vhost'`

Note the port number 5671, and keep 'amqp'.

Comment: Hey Lovisa, I have question about the celery producer. How does the producer securely push messages into the rabbitmq queue using SSL? The above `BROKER_URL` is only used by the workers for pulling out messages right?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your own Rabbit setup checkout this to make it secure.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html